# encode NSInteger doesn't work on 64 bit simulators - objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger, nscoder

I'm quite new to Objective c. In my app I want to save in a .plist file an object made of a NSString and three NSInteger token from three segmented controls. It is working fine on 32 bit simulators and devices, but in 64 bit a null object is passed, because of the NSCoder I guess.
In my class of the object I implemented these two methods:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject: self.cardPath forKey:@"cardPath"];
    [coder encodeInteger: (NSInteger) self.cardSign forKey:@"cardSign"];
    [coder encodeInteger: (NSInteger) self.cardNumber forKey:@"cardNumber"];
    [coder encodeInteger: (NSInteger) self.cardColor forKey:@"cardColor"];
} 

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self.cardPath = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"cardPath"];
    self.cardSign = (NSInteger*) [coder decodeIntegerForKey: @"cardSign"];
    self.cardNumber = (NSInteger*) [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"cardNumber"];
    self.cardColor = (NSInteger*) [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"cardColor"];
    return self;
}
```

I get the value from the segmented control:

```
cardSelected.cardSign = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
```

and

```
cardSelected.cardNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
```

and I compare like:

```
cardSelected.cardColor = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
if ([cardSelected.cardColor intValue] ==  0)
{
    [iBack setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"5_0.png"]];
    NSLog(@"red");
}
```

and I save the object:

```
'-(IBAction)game:(id)sender
{
      NSMutableArray *cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: cardSelected, nil];
      NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:cards];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"cards"];
      [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];}'
```

I try to retrieve the saved object in viewDidLoad method in this way

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// testing for 64bit at runtime

if (sizeof(void*) == 4) {
    NSLog(@"You're running in 32 bit");

} else if (sizeof(void*) == 8) {
    NSLog(@"You're running in 64 bit");
}

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[paths[0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"selectedCard.plist"]];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    segSign.momentary = NO;
    segNumber.momentary = NO;
    segColor.momentary = NO;

    [segSign addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedSign:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segNumber addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedNumber:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segColor addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedColor:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSData *cardsData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cards"];
    NSMutableArray *cards = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:cardsData];
    cardSelected = [cards objectAtIndex:0];


    //NSLog(@"%li",cardSelected.cardNumber);

    if ([cardSelected.cardColor intValue] ==  0)
    {
        [iBack setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"5_0.png"]];
        NSLog(@"red");
    }

    if ([cardSelected.cardColor intValue] ==  1)
    {
        [iBack setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"5_1.png"]];
        NSLog(@"blue");
    }

    [segSign setSelectedSegmentIndex: [cardSelected.cardSign intValue]];
    NSLog(@"check sign...%i", [cardSelected.cardSign intValue]); //always display 1
    NSLog(@"double-check...%@", cardSelected.cardSign); //always display 1
    [segNumber setSelectedSegmentIndex: [cardSelected.cardNumber intValue]];
    [segColor setSelectedSegmentIndex: [cardSelected.cardColor intValue]];

} else
{
    NSLog(@"else");
    Card *i = [[Card alloc]init];
    i.cardSign = 0;
    i.cardNumber = 0;
    i.cardPath = @"0_0.png";
    [iBack setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"5_0.png"]];
    cardSelected = i;
}




[iImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed : cardSelected.cardPath]];



// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

cardSelected is a object Card with .h file:

```
@interface Card : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
NSNumber *cardSign, *cardNumber, *cardColor;
NSString *cardPath;

}

@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *cardSign, *cardNumber, *cardColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cardPath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSCoder *coder, *encoder;

@end
```

and implementation .m file as

```
'
   @interface Card : NSObject { NSNumber *cardSign, *cardNumber, *cardColor; NSString *cardPath;

   }

   @property (nonatomic) NSNumber *cardSign, *cardNumber, *cardColor;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cardPath;
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSCoder *coder, *encoder;

   @end
```

'
When using the object (Card) *cardSelected it hasn't the expected values.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a quick comment: are you sure that you get no warnings whatsoever from the above code? Regardless of 32 or 64 - bit platform.

Comment: What precisely is not working???

Comment: There are no warnings, sure.

Answer (score 1):

You use NSInteger in a bad way.

NSInteger are scalar values (depending on the platform it can be int or long).

So when you do

```
cardSelected.cardSign = (NSInteger*) [sender selectedSegmentIndex];
```

it's wrong.

You should set the NSInteger ivar without the *.

Short answer : remove all stars after the NSInteger and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I was trying to store an object 'Card' made of three NSNumber using NSCoder. Now I store three NSNumber in a NSMutableArray, I write it to a plist file and without 'Card' class it works, in 32 bit and in 64 bit too. Thanks for helping, for a dummy it's better to simplify the code ;)